# How can I create a bar in the bottom of a Java app, like a status bar?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, statusbar

I am in the process of creating a Java app and would like to have a bar
on the bottom of the app, in which I display a text bar and a status (progress) bar.

Only I can't seem to find the control in NetBeans neither do I know the code to create in manually.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Create a JFrame or JPanel with a BorderLayout, give it something like a [BevelBorder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/border/BevelBorder.html) or line border so it is seperated off from the rest of the content and then add the status panel at BorderLayout.SOUTH.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.setSize(200, 200);

// create the status bar panel and shove it down the bottom of the frame
JPanel statusPanel = new JPanel();
statusPanel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
frame.add(statusPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
statusPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frame.getWidth(), 16));
statusPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(statusPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel("status");
statusLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
statusPanel.add(statusLabel);

frame.setVisible(true);
```

Here is the result of the above status bar code on my machine:

[image]

Comment: didn't work for me, the status bar ended up in the middle of the window

Comment: You need to use a different layout inside the JPanel. As in the code snippet above, BoxLayout will yield the result like in the picture.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately Swing does not have a native support for StatusBars.
You can use a `BorderLayout` and a label or whatever you need to display at the bottom:

```
public class StatusBar extends JLabel {

    /** Creates a new instance of StatusBar */
    public StatusBar() {
        super();
        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 16));
        setMessage("Ready");
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        setText(" "+message);        
    }        
}
```

Then in your Main Panel:

```
statusBar = new StatusBar();
getContentPane().add(statusBar, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

From: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/creating-a-status-bar.html

Comment: Using JPanel, instead of JLabel for a status bar is much better idea.

Comment: @Bozhidar Batsov: Yes, it is.

Answer (score 4):

I have used swing library from [L2FProd](http://www.l2fprod.com/common/download.ph). The Status bar library they have provided is very good.

Below is how you would use it:

1. Download the JAR they are providing and put it in your classpath
2. The status bar internally divides the bar area into zone. Each zone can contain a Component (JLabel, JButton, etc). Idea is to fill the bar with required zones and the components.
3. Instantiate the status bar as below....

   ```
   import java.awt.Component;
   import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
   import javax.swing.JLabel;
   import com.l2fprod.common.swing.StatusBar;

   StatusBar statusBar = new StatusBar();
   statusBar.setZoneBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY));
   statusBar.setZones(
       new String[] { "first_zone", "second_zone", "remaining_zones" },
       new Component[] {
           new JLabel("first"),
           new JLabel("second"),
           new JLabel("remaining")
       },
       new String[] {"25%", "25%", "*"}
   );
   ```
4. Now add the above `statusBar` to the main panel you have (BorderLayout and set it to the south side).

See a sample screenshot from one of the apps I am working on [here](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/8586/samplestatusbar.png) (it has 2 zones). Let me know if you face any issues....

Comment: Screenshot is a dead link.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the status bar component in the [SwingX library](http://swinglabs.org/projects.jsp) - Here is the API doc for the [status bar is here](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXStatusBar.html)

[A good example of its use is here.](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18979.html)

Have fun.

Comment: Pulling in the entire SwingX for a component that's trivial to implement doesn't seem like the best idea to me... If you're already using SwingX in the app, that's fine, but otherwise it's a complete overkill...

Answer (score 1):

For a more modern look than the accepted answer go with a GridBagLayout and a JSeparator:

```
JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 0;

JPanel menuJPanel = new JPanel();
menuJPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.RED));
outerPanel.add(menuJPanel, gbc);

gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc.weighty = 1;

JPanel contentJPanel = new JPanel();
contentJPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLUE));
outerPanel.add(contentJPanel, gbc);

gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.weighty = 0;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

outerPanel.add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL), gbc);
outerPanel.add(new JPanel(), gbc);
```

[image: screenshot of the result]